# Stitching together trajectories

Tags: drake

I'm attempting to construct a Drake `Trajectory` that is a concatenation of several other trajectories.

I want my robot to perform a sequence of actions, roughly equivalent to a pick and place. For each action, I use `KinematicTrajectoryOptimization` to generate the desired trajectory.

I want to join all these trajectories into one unified trajectory, so I can simulate the whole sequence in one pass. All the individual trajectories have `start_time` of zero. Is there a way of achieving this?

I attempted to use `CompositeTrajectory` but that requires the `start_time` of each input trajectory to coincide with the `end_time` of the previous one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found one way of doing this - use `PathParameterizedTrajectory` to shift the start/end times of each trajectory so they form contiguous ranges, then pass the results into `CompositeTrajectory`.

Comment: Can you post a code snippet of how you leveraged PathParameterizedTrajectory to shift the start and end times of each trajectory to form continuous ranges?